# Modify the response format of Spring data rest

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Right now Spring data rest APIs HAL format response. If there is success, I get the complete entity along with links, something like

```
{ 
name : Madhair,
links : '../users/123'
}
```

I want to define this contract myself. like

```
{ 
 status : 'success'
 result : 'actual created object',
 error : null
}
```

I dont want to use Filter or Interceptor. Is there a neat way to do this?sprin

Comment: Questions: Do you have source code access to the REST service? Can you do modification to the service itself ? planing to write an adapter service if between your current REST service and the consumer ?

Comment: "spring-data-rest" looks like you missed the point :)